# Can you call a CSS style sheet to an HTML document in an if statement

Tags: html, css, if-statement

I am trying to bring in an external style sheet from a css file in an if statement. I have several textboxes and I need for if on the click of a button a pop up come up and it say the entire form should be filled and the background color change to red. I have this in my HTML file:

```
<style type="text/css">

@import url("mysheet.css");

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform()
{
var x=document.forms["CustInfo"]["Fname"].value;
if (x == null || x == "")
{
    alert("The entire form must be filled out");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

In my CSS file I simply have:

```
.formalert{
    background-color: Red;
}
```

How can I change that "alert" to call my formalert?

Comment: You should be also working on a way to do server-side validation as well as Client-Side, if Javascript is disabled I dont see how your app is going to gracefully degraduate - you want to design websites with Progresive Enhancement in mind. ps As Tom mentioned go and mark some answers - people have spent good time helping you and given correct answers to your questions - the questions without answers marked can cause people to waste their time when a solution has been found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to always include the style, but only set your form to have that className if it fails validation.

```
<style type="text/css">
.formalert{
    background-color: Red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform(oForm)
{
    var x=document.forms["CustInfo"]["Fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "")
    {
        alert("The entire form must be filled out");
        oForm.className += ' formalert';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>        

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform(this);">
...
</form>
```

Comment: I am not real sure what you mean. This is literally the first time I've ever used HTML

Comment: I *think* what @samccone is hinting at, is there are newer ways to do this.  Nonetheless, the example is close to the code you provided.